# WEBブラウザのリンクからMonacaアプリを起動したときにパラメータを受け取りたい

Tags: android, monaca

Androidのみでいいのですが、WEBブラウザのリンクをクリックしたときに
起動するアプリケーションをMonacaで作成したいと考えています。

アプリの起動自体はできたのですが、そのときにそのリンクのURLの中に含まれている
パラメータ(またはそのURL自体でもいいです)をアプリで受け取りたいのですが、
その方法がわからず困っております。
(例えば、URL内に埋め込まれたIDをアプリで受け取って、そのIDに対応した内容の
アプリのページを表示させたい。)

一般的なアプリではインテント経由で受け取ったりするようですが、
MonacaのWebIntentプラグインでは調べてみても、別のアプリに渡す方法しか
見つけられませんでした。

Monacaアプリで実現できる方法をご存知の方、ご教授いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

起動自体はAndroidManifest.xmlに以下のように`intent-filter`タグ、`action`タグ、
`category`タグ、`data`タグを追加することで実現できました。

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="simple" />
</intent-filter>
```

呼び出しのリンクは以下です。

```
<a href="myapp://simple/command">TEST Link</a>
```

[こちらのサイト](http://www.ipentec.com/document/document.aspx?page=android-start-application-at-url-link-click-on-web-browser)を参考にしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monacaで作成したアプリをURLSchemeで起動することは出来ますが、
パラメータを付与して起動することは出来ません。
(MonacaのAndroidのMainActivityを編集することが出来ないため)

以前Assialの方へ要望として提出しましたが、未だに実装されていないのが現状です。